# matplotlib, scrapy packages cant be installed with Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, scrapy, pycharm

I installed Python 3.9.0 version and then Pycharm 2020.2 version after I format my laptop. Now I am facing problems with installing some packages such as matplotlib and scrapy and so on, there are some packages that are successful. I keep getting this notice in the link below from pycharm.

[Pycharm Notice Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLLqv.png)

Note: I only have one version of Python; that is, Python 3.9.0

Please Help!! Much Thanks

Comment: Please show the actual error instead of a link to a screenshot.

Comment: This looks like possible package incompatibilities with Python 3.9, since this version is quite new. I'd suggest to use Python 3.8.

Comment: @PApostol I also thought about this since version 3.9 is new, but still, It is not working with 3.8 version as well

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem for **Scrapy** you have to download from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) the win32 or win64 depending on your Windows system (the updated version), then move the wheel file that you downloaded to your Project Folder in **Pycharm** (copy/paste) then run the terminal and type:

`pip install Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl`      ===> For win32

`pip install Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`  ===> For win64

Now you can type in the terminal:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

Finally you will have correctly installed Scrapy.
If you have x64 Windows and Twisted win64 version gives you this error:

```
ERROR: Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

You have to use the x32 version.